# How to provide a function with an access to a specific environment (and its variables) in R?

Tags: r, environment-variables

If I define a function in the global environment, and call this function in an environment, the function does not have an access to the variables in the environment in which the function is being called, for example:

```
withfunction <- \(irisdf = iris) {
  with(iris,{
    secondfunction()
  })
}

secondfunction <- \() {
  print(head(iris))
  print(Sepal.Length)
}

> withfunction()
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
Error in secondfunction() : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

Following my example, is there a way to access variables in the environment defined as an argument for the with() function?

Of course, I could define secondfunction() that way it takes arguments, and pass all the variables to it, but if I had more than one function in the same environment, then I had to modify all of them.

So, is there a way that function could somehow access all the variables from the environment it is being called?

Comment: Should your first function be `with(irisdf, secondfunction())`? You're not currently using `irisdf`. As it currently is your second function could say `print(get("Sepal.Length", envir = parent.frame()))`. But it shouldn't. Don't go down this road - any time saved in not passing the parameters to your function will be outweighed by lack of readability and surprising bugs which might go unnoticed for some time.

Comment: With [very few exceptions](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/mice/html/with.mids.html), you shouldn't use `with` in functions. Use proper functional programming and pass parameters.